# Formatting scientific number representation in xsl

Tags: xslt, numbers, format

I have the following value in my XML `-1.8959581529998104E-4`.  I want to format this to the exact number it should be using XSL to give me `-0.000189595815299981`.

```
format-number(-1.8959581529998104E-4,'0.000000;-0.000000') gives me NaN.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0 does not have support for scientific notation.**

This: `number('-1.8959581529998104E-4')`
Result: `NaN`

This: `number('-0.000189595815299981')`
Result: `-0.000189595815299981`

XSLT 2.0 has support for scientific notation

This: `number('-1.8959581529998104E-4')`
Result: `-0.000189595815299981`

**EDIT**: A very simple XSLT 1.0 workaround:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="number[substring-after(.,'E')]">
        <xsl:variable name="vExponent" select="substring-after(.,'E')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vMantissa" select="substring-before(.,'E')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vFactor"
             select="substring('100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
                               1, substring($vExponent,2) + 1)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with($vExponent,'-')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$vMantissa div $vFactor"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vMantissa * $vFactor"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<number>-1.8959581529998104E-4</number>
```

Output:

```
-0.00018959581529998104
```

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks again!!!  I'm trying to get my transform to work using VS2008 in the IDE.  Do I need to do something to force it to use version 2.0 for xsl?  I.e <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> ?

Comment: Just looked on MSDN Forums and version 2.0 is not supported in VS2008.  :-(

Comment: @Andez: It looks like you can use a XSLT 2.0 implementation, but you can't integrate them with VS. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099051/saxon-with-visual-studio-2010-is-there-a-way-to-use-the-debugger

Comment: The template posted in this answer doesn't correctly handle positive exponents when they are not preceded by a '+' symbol (e.g. 2E4), see my modified version below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671831/2047725

Answer (score 4):

This is based on user357812 answer. But I made it act like a function and handle non-scientific notation

```
<xsl:template name="convertSciToNumString" >
    <xsl:param name="inputVal" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vExponent" select="substring-after($inputVal,'E')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vMantissa" select="substring-before($inputVal,'E')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vFactor"
         select="substring('100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
                           1, substring($vExponent,2) + 1)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($inputVal)=$inputVal">
            <xsl:value-of select="$inputVal"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($vExponent,'-')">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($vMantissa div $vFactor, '#0.#############')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($vMantissa * $vFactor, '#0.#############')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Usage:

```
<xsl:template match="X">
    <X>
        <xsl:call-template name="convertSciToNumString">
            <xsl:with-param name="inputVal" select="text()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </X>    
</xsl:template>
```

This should handle a mix of scientific notation and decimal values.

Comment: The template posted in this answer doesn't correctly handle positive exponents when they are not preceded by a '+' symbol (e.g. 2E4), see my modified version below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56671831/2047725

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround without a template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" ... xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java">
...
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(java:java.lang.Double.parseDouble('1E-6'), '0.000')"/>
```

Comment: Works on Java, not other other XSLT implementations. :)

Answer (score 1):

The logic doesn't appear to work correctly in the above answers by [Moop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27369614/2047725) and [user357812](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367826/2047725) when determining `vFactor` in one particular scenario.

If `vExponent` is a single-digit positive number (without a preceding '+' sign), then `vFactor` is set to an empty string. This is because an assumption was made that the 1st character of `vExponent` would be a plus/minus sign and therefore the 2nd character onwards were of interest. The `vMantissa` variable is then multiplied by an empty string which results in the template outputting `NaN`.

If `vExponent` is a multi-digit positive number (without a preceding '+' sign), then `vFactor` is set to an incorrect value. Because of the aforementioned assumption, the 1st digit is ignored and the `vMantissa` is then multiplied by an incorrect `vFactor`.

Therefore, I've modified the previously posted code a little so that it can handle scientific numbers of the forms: 2E-4, 2E+4 and 2E4.

```
<xsl:template name="convertSciToNumString" >
    <xsl:param name="inputVal" select="0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vMantissa" select="substring-before(., 'E')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vExponent" select="substring-after(., 'E')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vExponentAbs" select="translate($vExponent, '-', '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vFactor" select="substring('100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 1, substring($vExponentAbs, 1) + 1)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($inputVal)=$inputVal">
            <xsl:value-of select="$inputVal"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with($vExponent,'-')">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($vMantissa div $vFactor, '#0.#############')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>         
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($vMantissa * $vFactor, '#0.#############')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But this broke exponents that _do_ have a '+' sign (at least in mono's XSLT processor). If you change the line to select="translate(translate($vExponent, '-', ''), '+', ''", it fixes the bug. I would do an edit but that seems rude.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this with xsltproc using libxslt1.1 in version 1.1.24 under Linux:

XSLT 1.1 is able to read in exponential/scientific format now even without any dedicated template, it seems to simply work  :-))