# Convert exponential format into numeric format in XSLT

Tags: function, math, xslt, numeric, exponential

I have to convert within my XSLT number in exponential format ( i.e: 1,2345E7 ) into numeric ( i.e: 12340000 ).
What would the a XSLT function to achieve this.

Comment: Exact duplicate [Formatting scientific number representation in xsl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367737/formatting-scientific-number-representation-in-xsl)

Comment: Check my succinct implementation.

Comment: I think the answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367737/formatting-scientific-number-representation-in-xsl

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but this implementation claims to do what you ask:  http://www.orm-designer.com/article/xslt-convert-scientific-notation-to-decimal-number

Answer (score 0):

XSLT 2.0 accepts exponential notation for numbers on input, XSLT 1.0 does not. So the answer rather depends which version you are using (I suspect you are using 1.0, because otherwise you wouldn't need to ask for help). On the output side, you can control the format using format-number() with either version.

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0 and need to convert from exponential to numeric since the program that uses thoe XMLs does not support exponential format

Comment: +1 Good answer. @Daniel: question is unclear about whether you have such notation in input source or you want this for your output.