# How to convert double value to exponential in xslt

Tags: xslt, exponential

I need to convert double value to exponential value by using xslt, and i think this we can do by using format-number function but i don't 've any idea how to convert by using this so any one help me out.

Thanks,
@nag

Comment: exponential value? What does that mean? Examples please.

Comment: numeric: 12340000 exponential value for that numeric: 12345E7

Comment: please go through this link, but i want reverse from that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266879/convert-exponential-format-into-numeric-format-in-xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no support for output in scientific notation in XSLT 1.0, and only very limited support in XSLT 2.0. (In XSLT 2.0, conversion from double to string uses scientific notation for absolute values outside the range 1e-6 to 1e+6, and there is no way of controlling this, although you can avoid it completely by converting via decimal.)