# XML Strings to Numbers using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting, transform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formatting scientific number representation in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367737/formatting-scientific-number-representation-in-xsl)

I have an XML file which I'm hoping to format using XSLT and produce another XML file.

The input is like so:

```
<Sale>
  <office>NY</office>
  <origQty>2.0E7</origQty>
  <shortQty>2.0E7</shortQty>
  <price>0.0</price>
  <qty>10000000</qty>
</Sale>
```

The XSLT reads as follows. Basically I'm trying to do a global copy and then work on the elements I choose:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
  indent="no" />
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="qty">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="qty"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="shortQty">
      <xsl:value-of select="shortQty"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="origQty">
    <xsl:element name="origQty">
      <xsl:value-of select="number(origQty) + 1"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current output I get is like so:

```
<Sale>
  <office>NY</office>
  <origQty>NaN</origQty>
  <price>0.0</price>
  <qty />
</Sale>
```

You can see I've been experimenting with different ways of capturing the data I want, with little success. The idea is to grab the quantities and then format them in my own way. So I'd like to:

- get the value of the element
- convert it to a number
- do some maths with it ( +1,  div 1000, whatever)
- output it back to the XML

After researching this I thought number() was my best shot but as you can see that gives me NaN... Any advice as to what I should be doing here?

Thanks,
Dave.